# Can I get some assistance with my homework to Compute Tips For Services Rendered?

Tags: vb.net

The program should request the person’s occupation, the amount of the bill, and the percentage tip as input and pass this information to a Sub procedure to display the person and the tip. Title is gratuities, first line Person’s occupation, amount of the bill:, Percentage tip: Compute Tip, and show the tip. Im not sure how to approach it properly. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub btnCompute_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As _
    System.EventArgs) Handles btnCompute.Click

    Dim Occupation As String = CStr(txtOccupation.Text)
    Dim Bill As Double = CDbl(txtBill.Text)
    Dim Tip As Double = CDbl(txtTip.Text)

    lstOuput.Text = 'hmmmmm.....'



End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: Spec isn't complete, what format is the percentage entered? What should happen if the user enters in decimal format (0.15) or includes the % symbol in the text, or worse yet both?

Answer (score 1):

```
lstOutput.Text = Bill * (1 + If(Tip<1,Tip,Tip/100))
```

Comment: It says "Expression Expected" for If

Comment: What version of vb.net? This requires VS2008.  VS2005 would need IIF() instead.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have assigned the Bill and Tip to double variables, you can assign the gratuity amount into another variable, or output it directly.

```
Dim Gratuity as Double = Bill * Tip

lstOutput.text = "Total Bill + Gratuity = " & string.format(Bill + Gratuity, "c")
```